# 3.marker.challenge. is this haraam？

Tags: halal-haram, game

the 3 marker challenge is a game where you are  blindfolded and you pick 3 random marker. Is it haraam to play this game? PLease let me.know soon, In Sha Allah.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as there is no gambling involved this game is very halal.